# $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix. Prove $\bar{A}A$ is similar to $A\bar{A}$ (or disprove)?(Solved, it is true.)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is a $n \times n$ complex matrix. Prove $\bar{A}A$ is similar to $A\bar{A}$? I assume $\bar{A}$ here means just the complex conjugate of $A$. It is not the conjugate transpose as I know in that case they are similar.

Any ideas that could help? Thanks! If anyone could disprove it that is also good.

**Update** This problem has been solved. See the comments below. Once figured out that $AB$ and $BA$ has the same nonsingular Jordan block, the singular part could be matched by considering that the solutions of $(\bar{A}A)^kx=0$ and $(A\bar{A})^kx=0$ are conjugate to each other (thus one-to-one).

Comment: Are you sure of what you are asking?

Comment: Yes I am sure. This statement may be wrong, I don't know. It seems weird. Maybe one could disprove it.

Comment: If $A$ (equivalently $\bar A$) is invertible, then this is obvious

Comment: Also, $A\bar A$ and $\bar AA$ will necessarily have the same eigenvalues. The only thing that "can go wrong" is that they have different Jordan structures for $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: I think I get it. They should have the same rank for any power of them, as you can just take the complex conjugate of the solution x(eigenvalue w.r.t. 0).

Comment: @Gnon I didn't have any solution in mind when I made my comment, but that absolutely works! Well done

Answer (score 1):

It's true. Two complex square matrices $A$ and $B$ are said to be *consimilar* if $A=\overline{S}BS^{-1}$ for some invertible complex matrix $S$. It is straightforward to verify that if $A$ and $B$ are consimilar, then $A\overline{A}$ and $B\overline{B}$ are similar. Now, every complex square matrix $A$ is consimilar to $\overline{A}$ (see e.g. corollary 4.11 of Hong and Horn, [*A canonical form for matrices under consimilarity*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(88)90324-2), LAA 102: 143-168 (1988)). Therefore $A\overline{A}$ is similar to $\overline{A}A$.